# validar y restringir datos en una bd

Tags: validación

amigos que tal, tengo una duda la cual quisiera que alguien me pueda dar una solucion. tengo una tabla creada en bd postgres con campòs id, nombre, codigo y estado y necesito restringir y validar dos campos.

el campo codigo es de tipo string pero debe alamacenar solo numeros, eso incluye que el cero se lea, por ejemplo que el campo codigo siendo string guarde 0001 pero que NO guarde letra y asi susecivamente.
el campo estado debe dar tres condiciones. si fuese 0 = cancelado si fuese 1 = funcionando y si fuese 2 = paralizado. se agradece

Comment: me queda la duda con la lógica que mencionas, debe ser numérico pero debe ser formato string?

Comment: Hola @user92645, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0):

**Cambia los tipos de datos en tu tabla**

*Si ya la creaste debes de hacer un alter table o un update, si quieres que codigo guarde solo numeros puedes usar un*

```
ALTER TABLE nombredelatabla
modify codigo tinyint(4);
```

*ese para cambiar el campo codigo, ya despues solo te aceptara caracteres numericos como tu buscas y sobre estado puedes hacer lo siguiente:*

```
ALTER TABLE nombredelatabla
modify estado BOOLEAN;
```

*y pues usar un estado cancelado es algo poco eficiente pero puedes tomar el 0 como falso y cualquier otro valor como verdadero*

**Espero haberte sido de ayuda**

Comment: Claro esto si ya creaste la tabla, si no en el create statement, utilizas los datos así como te explique

Comment: El alter solo lo debe ejecutar si no tiene datos almacenados con otro tipo de dato de lo contrario habrá fallo

Comment: Si, muy cierto, bueno si asi fuera lo mejor seria crearse una tabla a partir de esa tabla luego haciendo alter table y por ultimo migrando los datos, gracias por recordar ese detalle